# Regular expression to match complex strings or lines

Tags: regex, maven-plugin, header-files

I've to check header portion of code of some java classes, I'm using maven-license-plugin and I've to specify in a common header (textual) file a regular expression to allow lines like that:

`Portions Copyrighted 2013 andrea`

or

`Copyright 2008-2009 Company, Inc. All rights reserved.`

can you help me?

a template of header is:

```
====================
DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.

Copyright 2008-2009 company, Inc. All rights reserved.

The contents of this file are subject to the terms of the Common Development 
and Distribution License("CDDL") (the "License"). You may not use this file 
except in compliance with the License.

You can obtain a copy of the License at https://xxx.yy.com/licenses/CDDL
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations 
under the License. 

When distributing the Covered Code, include this CDDL Header Notice in each file
and include the License file at https://xxx.yy.com/licenses/CDDL.
If applicable, add the following below this CDDL Header, with the fields 
enclosed by brackets [] replaced by your own identifying information: 
"Portions Copyrighted [year] [name of copyright owner]"
====================
```

Comment: can you say something about the rules? such as which character is not change and which characters will change?

Comment: and I've to be able to recognize the template posted plus a line at the end of file such that Portions Copyrighted 2013 andrea, and an addition line after first copyright like that: Copyright 2008-2009 Company, Inc. All rights reserved.

Comment: the only changes to this template are these two possible additions, the whole remaining text is the same

Comment: You're taking the problem too lightly, what if there was `&copy;` or `©` instead of copyright ? Or maybe in another language `droit d'auteur` ?

Comment: nothing of this situations is allowed because I've already files with headers and I read all the files, the only differences between files are those I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
^.*Copyright(ed)?\s+\d+(-\d+)?.+$
```

Comment: and if I've to check presence or not of a blank line?

Comment: I think your suggestion is very close to right answer, but maven plugin still doesn't work, maybe doesn't recognize possible blank lines at the end of file before "Portion Copyrighted ..."

Comment: I made some tests with neatbeans, your expression is almost perfect, but doesn't match this case: "Copyright (c) 2011-2013 ForgeRock AS. All Rights Reserved"

Comment: Thanks to @Tim.Tang the solution is:

^.*Copyright(ed)?(\s(c))\s+\d+(-\d+)?.+$